# What is the right approach for this requirements?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath, forms-services, forms-library, email-enabled-library

Need to build the form in SharePoint 2010, where

1. Logged in user should able to select the domain user to send email from drop down (certainly need to access the domain users in drop down list).
2. Second is, user should be able to select the congratulation message or subject from another list of string and user should able to select the greeting (for greeting created the picture library. so need to access this in my form along with thumbnail or something like that, and should comment something as email message. and should send an email to selected user.
   [image]

Which approach i have to follow / Better ? can we do this in SharePoint designer, VS SharePoint Solutions or else, Infopath forms? I am no longer SharePoint Developer since past 5 years. Now I need guidance for this.

Comment: any luck for me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO the technically best approach would be to develop a **custom SharePoint solution (WSP) with Visual Studio**: no functional constrain, evolutivity, easiness of deployment and updates, robustness, etc.
The only downside I can see is: you need a SharePoint developer!

Second best option would be **InfoPath**.
Usually, I don't recommend InfoPath at all, because it's a poor solution when it comes to evolutivity and possibility to deploy it from dev to production. And also Microsoft is not clear about the future of InfoPath.
But here, your requirements are quite simple and can easily be achieved with InfoPath with not too many tricks/hacks (InfoPath hacks usually make the solution a nightmare to deploy/maintain). Your IP form would contain 4 simple fields (a people picker for *To*, a dropdown list for *Subject*, something-yet-to-be-determined for the card selection and a textbox for the *Comment*. IP can easily send emails.
Warning: displaying images in *Form Services* (Web mode of InfoPath) is no supported.

Comment: Well, Or can we say this is possible in out of the box SharePoint 2010

Comment: If by "out-of-the-box" you mean no dev, no InfoPath, no SPD, no JavaScript... I can't think of any solution.

Comment: Done by Visual WebPart template in VS 2012